# Reference Data/Master data in NOSQL databases

Tags: cassandra, hbase, rdbms, accumulo, nosql

I am trying to build a solution to migrate existing relational data warehouse in NoSql database. I am thinking of using cassandra or accumulo or Hbase. 
The problem I am facing is

Existing RDBMS has reference data (Codes, a description used by source system). 
Example - Account table has Account type cd, Account status cd. Both are coming from the source system and maintained in separate reference data tables in order to standardize and make more meaningful.
Every new code coming from the source flows in these tables first and then into Account table by joining with these tables.

How do we handle such scenarios in NOSQL databases in absence of Joins?
How do we maintain master data/reference in NOSQL databases?

Answer (score 0):

You **should** watch data-modelling course on a [**Datastax Academy DS220**](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling)

> **If you wanna use Cassandra, you play with her rules.** Or you will loose

---

You can not handle such scenarios. No joins at all. Data should be saved in form, that end-client wanna get from you. 
In short:

1. Make conceptual model (can be copied drom Relational DB)
2. Find all queries, and make C* tables for them.

DENORMALIZE )

Comment: I am aware of cassandra database and how the model works in cassandra. Till now we had no issue as we were using cassandra for creating analytical models which were based on user queries. I agree with the high level of denormalization. What I need to know now is from data migration perspective. I know it will be a complete redesign in terms of NoSQL database. What I am trying to know is how to handle reference data/master data when we are thinking of creating single customer view considering the single source of truth.

Comment: Sorry, can not help without example.